# creating ssh connection in shell script with password

Tags: bash, ssh

I can log on to a client using a username and password.  I know ssh keys are better and more secure, but for now I still want to do this with a password.

```
[michael@devserver ~]$ ssh -p 3333  -D 3333 testuser@localhost
testuser@localhost's password:
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 3333
Could not request local forwarding.

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Thu Nov 16 17:46:54 2017 from localhost
testuser@mypi:~ $
```

I would like to do the same but in a script.  My attempt is below.  When trying however, I am still prompted for a password.  I will also later try doing so using ssh keys as shown in my commented out line.

```
#!/bin/sh
userServer='serveruser'
userClient='clientuser'
passwordServer='serverpassword'
passwordClient='clientpassword'
passwordClient=3333

if echo $passwordClient | ssh -p $port $userClient@localhost | grep ECDSA;  then
# or if keys are used:
# if su -c "ssh -p $port $userClient@localhost" $userServer | grep ECDSA;  then
        echo 'Logon successful'
else
        echo 'Connection refused'
fi
```

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202587/automatically-enter-ssh-password-with-script

Comment: @CarlLöndahl  No, I read several others recommending `expect`.  Looks right on target.  Thank you